# Trying to convert a map location to a string

Tags: swiftui, mapkit

I am trying to take an object of a map location and convert it into a string to send to a URL.

This is my code right now:

```
 List{ 
       ForEach(self.places, id: \.id) { places in
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                **let address = String(places.title)**
                Button(action:{
                    goToMap(Address:address)
                }){
                    Text(places.name)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                }
                    Text(places.title)
                }
           }         
       }
}
```

Using address as defined above causes the program to fail.
In place of the bolded line I have also tried:

```
 //let address = String(decoding: places.title, as: UTF8.self)
```

but I get the error:

> Initializer 'init(decoding:as:)' requires the types 'String.Element'
> (aka 'Character') and         'Unicode.UTF8.CodeUnit' (aka 'UInt8') be
> equivalent

*places.title is the location I am trying to convert*

any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: is `places.title` a `CLLocation` or `CLLocationCoordinate2D`. If so, what exactly do you want to convert to a String,
 the lat,long? Note: you should rename this to `place.title`, no `s`. Show the code for `places`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set variables inside the view like that in SwiftUI

```
 List{ 
       ForEach(self.places, id: \.id) { places in
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                Button(action:{
                    // you may set variables and convert your string to the proper url here inside the button action
                    // let url = String(places.title) ?? "" . . .
                    goToMap(url)
                }){
                    Text(places.name)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                }
                    Text(String(places.title) ?? "")
                }
           }         
       }
}
```